# how to draw points as textures/text on touch in opengl-es in android?

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, texture2d

I want to draw points on touch. Each point loads textures/Default text as shown below.How to start to draw this kind of stuff in opengl-es in android?

[image: texture]

[image: text]

Comment: Not and answer to your question, but for starters to get an idea these will help. http://www.learnopengles.com/android-lesson-one-getting-started/ and https://www.toptal.com/opengl/opengl-tutorial-for-android-building-a-mandelbrot-set-generator

Answer (score 0):

To use a texture for your point, you can use these lines of code in your fragment shader.

```
lowp vec4 diffuse_color = texture2D(texture1, gl_PointCoord);
gl_FragColor = vec4(color.xyz, diffuse_color.x);
```

Make sure the `gl_PointSize` in the vertex shader is large enough.